# Get min from one column and each value from another only once with min rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Problem:** We want only the minimum jobrank for each df. Then among those, we want every job to appear, but only once with the minimum mf value.
Here's the table structure I have
I have one table with DF entries. Lets call it DfTable

```
DF
1
2
3
```

Another table2 as follows

```
MF  DF   Job  JobRank
-------------------
1   1    1     1
2   1    1     1
3   1    2     1
4   2    3     2
5   3    4     3
6   3    5     4
```

MF is unique, DF can be multiple.

Output should be: MF should be unique, DF should be unique per Job with minimum rank.

```
MF  DF   Job
-------------
1   1    1
3   1    2
4   2    3
5   3    4
```

So far this is what I have:

```
Select T2.MF, T1.DF, T2.Job
From table1 As T1
Inner Join table2 As T2 On T1.DF = T2.DF
Where JobRank = (
    Select Min(JobRank)
    From table2 As T3
    Where T3.DF = T2.DF
)
```

Comment: ok let me post my so far solution.

Comment: What is an "item"?  I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Please clearly explain the logic for choosing the rows.

Comment: Updated output as well as added more description of what the result should look like.

Comment: We need to know the logic. That one line with 10+ words doesn't tell us much on the logic required. You need to explain more in details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now.  You want only the minimum `jobrank` for each `df`.  Then among those, you want every job to appear, but only once with the minimum `mf` value.

Here is a method using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by df, job, jobrank order by mf) as seqnum_djj,
             min(jobrank) over (partition by df) as min_jobrank
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum_djj = 1 and jobrank = min_jobrank;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=609e1aa3b9d226cfe877e8b35678fda0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Added more context to the question

Comment: This doesn't work. This is similar to what I have.

Comment: yes, the fiddle looks good. Your description is better than mine, so I'll update the question. Let me try this.

Comment: If you were me, how would you describe the question ?